# How can I stop REF errors?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP("Processed Units Forecast",'IB ALPS'!$A$59:$K$1000,MATCH(Date1,INDEX('IB ALPS'!$1:$1048576,3,1):INDEX('IB ALPS'!$1:$1048576,3,11),0),FALSE),"N/A")
```

Hello, so I'm having an issue with this formula. I have a macro that deletes some of the DATA on the IB ALPS sheet. By the time the macro is finished, all of the referenced cells/ranges are fixed, but somewhere in the middle it creates a REF error @ `$A$59:$K$1000`(because of that split second where the cells are deleted). How can I stop excel from editing the function in that 1 second down time that the macro has, or how can I edit the function to keep referring to that range without immediately adding a REF.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the ability to edit the macro, you can temporarily disable calculation for your sheet while deleting the cells:

```vb
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("IB ALPS").EnableCalculation = False
' Some code that deletes rows goes here
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("IB ALPS").EnableCalculation = True
```

This should prevent the functions on that sheet from thinking that anything has gone wrong. See the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.enablecalculation) on this property for more information.